# Stop web.archive.org to save the site pages

Tags: robots.txt

I tried accessing `facebook.com` webpages from previous time.
And the site showed me an error that it can not save pages because of the site robots.txt/

Can anyone tell which statements in the `robots.txt` are making the site inaccessible to `web.archive.org`
I guess it is because of the #permission statement as mentioned here (http://facebook.com/robots.txt)

Is there any other way I can do this for my site as well.

I also don't want `woorank.com` or `builtwith.com` to analyze  my site.

Note: search engine bots should face no problems while crawling my site and indexing it if I add some statements to `robots.txt` in order to achieve results which are mentioned above.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask similar questions there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Archive (archive.org) crawler uses the User-Agent value `ia_archiver` (see [their documentation](https://archive.org/about/exclude.php)).

So if you want to target this bot in your robots.txt, use

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
```

And this is exactly [what Facebook does in its robots.txt](http://facebook.com/robots.txt):

> ```
> User-agent: ia_archiver
> Allow: /about/privacy
> Allow: /full_data_use_policy
> Allow: /legal/terms
> Allow: /policy.php
> Disallow: /
> ```

Comment: thanks unor, is there any solution for woorank.com and builtwith.com

Comment: @Krill: If you want to know if their bots support robots.txt, you should consult their documentation or ask their support. If not successful, you might want to ask on [webmasters.se] (however, check first if such questions are on-topic there).

Comment: It no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2017, archive.org bot does not respect robots.txt anymore.

I inspected what traces the bot leaves. I created a test.php page, that writes the $_SERVER variable to a txt file:

```php
file_put_contents("request.txt", json_encode($_SERVER) );
```

These were the relevant headers:

```
{
  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR": "207.241.225.246",
  "HTTP_USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/605.1.15",
  "HTTP_VIA": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; archive.org_bot; Wayback Machine Live Record; http://archive.org/details/archive.org_bot), Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; archive.org_bot; Wayback Machine Live Record; http://archive.org/details/archive.org_bot), 1.1 warcprox",
...
}
```

You can block the bot if you find "archive.org_bot" string in the HTTP_VIA header:

```php
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']) && str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'], "archive.org_bot") ) 
{
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you would like to submit a request for archives of your site **or
> account to be excluded from web.archive.org**, send us a request to
> info@archive.org and indicate:

https://help.archive.org/help/how-do-i-request-to-remove-something-from-archive-org/